# PSR 4 Class use error

Tags: php, psr-4, guzzle

This is my code :

```
use Ordering\Controllers\DefaultController as DefaultController;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
namespace Ordering\Controllers;


class OrderController extends DefaultController
{

    public function placeOrder()
    {
        $client         = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => getenv('GOD')]);
        $response       = $client->request('POST', 'v1/order/placeorder');
        $this->data     = json_decode($response->getBody());
    }

}
```

I am trying to import the GuzzleHttp\Client and use it in this class.
But the issue is

Am always receving the error:

```
Class 'Ordering\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
```

Anybody know how to correct it?

Comment: always put `namespace` on top. The first line after `<?php`

Comment: `$client  = new Client(['base_uri' => getenv('GOD')]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\` infront

`$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => getenv('GOD')]);`